# How to convert simple Curl call to Java HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, http, curl, httpurlconnection

Simple curl call that works is:
`curl https://api.github.com/search/repositories\?q\=reactive`

What I'm attempting right now in Java

```
                URL url = new URL("https://api.github.com/search/repositories\\?q\\=reactive");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    con.setReadTimeout(5000);

    int isError = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Error code is " + isError);

    InputStream error = con.getErrorStream();

    System.out.println("Error is " + error.toString() + " \n");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content.append(inputLine);
    }
    System.out.println("Error: " + content.toString());
```

Error code: `404`

Error message: `Error: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}`

Why would it not be found when I search it in that manner?

Thank you!

Comment: `error.toString()` is not going to print out the error message. Consider reading the stream and post the error message here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are using in java code is wrong with escape characters used for curl. Remove the escape characters and use the url `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=reactive`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=reactive");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        con.setReadTimeout(5000);

        System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
}
```

Output:

```
OK
```